# Does the word 'bazaar' instead of 'market' seem more catchy?

Tags: editing, word-choice

Under what specific condition should I use 'bazaar'and what famous writers have used it? I know some Indian writers have, but does someone know any notable English writer who has used that word?

Comment: You should visit a bazaar before writing about one. It's significantly different from neat westerner's market. It's like you'd ask "Can I use the word 'Musical' instead of 'Opera'?"

Comment: It's all about setting; set your story in the east, or an eastern style land? Call it a bazaar. Set it in Croydon? Call it a market. I don't see the words as interchangeable, because they provide very different imagery.

Comment: @SF.I have actually visited a bazaar, because once I lived near a bazaar where people used to shout for things to sell,where fruits/vegetables did not have any sort of certification like I see here! I grew up near a bazaar, in a small village!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I hear market, I see a teeny tiny bit of organization, stacks of fresh oranges, an early morning crowd and a women talking about inviting her husband's boss and his wife over for dinner.

When I hear the word bazaar, I see a dense street; stalls lining up on both sides of the street, aromas of different spices, a dense crowd and a fast chase scene.

It all depends on the tone of the scene. As a writer, you should be more interested in choosing the right words to set the right mood. Also, I agree with Nubia on the regional factor. However, I personally don't consider it. I'm fine with a few technical errors as long as it's setting the right visual I want it to set.

EDIT:

I just stumbled upon this yesterday night while reading the novel.
The word bazaar is used by Robert Ludlum in The Bourne Supremacy when Jason Bourne is asked to meet The Taipan in the Walled City in Kowloon. Again, notice how he used the word Bazaar instead of the term market.

Answer (score 2):

Looking in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bazaar?s=t), the word **bazaar** is a marketplace *especially one in the Middle East*. Those Indian writers might be accustomed in using the word "bazaar" instead of "market" (although India is not actually part of Middle East).

Another definition of bazaar is

> (esp in the Orient) a market area, esp a street of small stalls.

**Bazaar** is used mainly in Asia, so those English writers may not be used to that word.

Comment: Polish word for it is bazar :)

Answer (score 0):

When I hear market I think of someplace where I can find what I'm looking to buy, sometimes something I didn't know about.

When I hear bazaar I think of someplace where I might eventually find what I looking to buy, but will definitely find things I didn't know anyone would sell.

I have read both words in so many places, I don't pay any special attention. It would be like asking which writers of westerns used the word fireplace. (probably most of them).